# In Rust, why do we need to specify a reference variable is mutable each time we change its value?

Tags: rust, mutable

In the following guessing game, from the Rust Book, why do we have to say that the reference to the variable `.read_line(&mut guess)` is mutable since we already stated it was mutable in a previous line     `let mut guess = String::new();`?

```
use std::io; 

fn main() { 
    println!("Guess the number!"); 

    println!("Please input your guess."); 

    let mut guess = String::new(); 

    io::stdin() 
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line"); 

    println!("You guessed: [guess]"); 
}
```

Comment: Because you can have an immutable reference to a mutable thing. Consider the case where you have a `mut T` and you want to be able to update it but you want someone else to be able to *read* but **not** modify it. So you give them a `&T` instead of `&mut T`.

Comment: `let mut` signals that the variable *allows* mutable usage, but doesn't make it mutable in all contexts. `&mut` actually passes it as mutable, allowing the function to mutate the thing